# How to check and upgrade Bash on FreeBSD - related to the Shellshock bug

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, shellshock-bash-bug

I read the article *[A Bash Code Injection Vulnerability via Specially Crafted Environment Variables (CVE-2014-6271)](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223)* this morning when I came into work. I have updated [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) on most of my systems that I am responsible for, however, I was asked to upgrade Bash on a couple of [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) servers.

How do I check which version of Bash is running on FreeBSD and how do I patch it to get rid of this exploit?

Comment: You can check using `echo $BASH_VERSION`.  I can't supply a patch, but one temporary fix would be to install Korn shell (ksh) and make sh a symbolic link to ksh.  Korn shell does not have this bug because it does not support exported functions.

Comment: Questions about installing software are not questions about programming.

Comment: Maybe it could be migrated — with answers? — to the Unix/Linux or to the Server SE site?

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald it was a user [on that site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) that [discovered the vulnerability](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2014/q3/649) don't you think we already have like metrics crap tons of duplicates?

Comment: @Braiam I was not aware of this, migrating is probably useless then.

Comment: I have no problem doing what is necessary to keep the question in line with the post, however, I am unsure of what I should do with this post.

Comment: I would like to qualify my comment about Korn shell yesterday.  It turns out that Sun's XPG4 compliant Korn shell has the vulnerability as well.  Unlike regular ksh, the XPG4 version supports function exporting, as bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can verify the installed version of `bash` with

```
pkg info bash
```

The patched version of `bash` is [already in the ports tree](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/shells/bash/Makefile?revision=369261&view=markup), you can therefore upgrade it like any application.

Once `bash` has been rebuilt by the package build farm, you can upgrade `bash` as you would upgrade any package, with

```
pkg upgrade bash
```

If you are not familiar with `pkg` you should read the [appropriate chapter in the Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html).

**Important note.**  At the time of writing it seems that the package is not yet available, so here is the manual procedure to build your own package from sources:

**1.** Be sure to [upgrade your ports tree](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html) before trying to upgrade.

**2.** Move your shell to the ports directory and build

```
cd /usr/ports/shell/bash
make BATCH=yes build
```

**3.** Replace the old `batch` with

```
make BATCH=yes deinstall
make BATCH=yes reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this *Ask Ubuntu* answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/528102/321719), a command to check this is:

```
env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'
```

If you get `vulnerable`, it's still vulnerable.

This should work with Bash on any system to test the vulnerability, AFAIK. I've tested on [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions) and [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux), but they're not BSDs. To check the version, it should be similar to other systems:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.11(1)-release
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

See the [FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=48165) for more information on downloading/installing the patch. From that link:

> Everything before 4.3.25 is vulnerable, 4.3.25 should contain the fix.